# Random generate a year within a range

Tags: java, random

Ive got this java class where I want to randomly generate a year between 2020 and 2022 using random class .I know the code below wont do the trick so can you please help me

Random random = new Random();

int year=random.nextInt(2022-2020 +1);

Comment: Your range size is `3`. The base number is `2020`. Pick a rand num `0 <= r <= 2` then add `2020`.

Comment: Just add 2020 to your result. Generally `random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;`

Answer (score 1):

`.nextInt(x)` returns a random number between 0 and x-1, inclusive. `2022-2020+1` is constant. Just do the math: It's an inconvenient, lengthy way of writing `3`. `.nextInt(3)` will return a `0` 33% of the time, a `1` 33% of the time, and a `2` 33% of the time. Not what you wanted. What you wanted is a `2020` 33% of the time, a `2021` 33% of the time, and a `2022` 33% of the time.

Now how do you turn 0/1/2 into 2020/2021/2022...

I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader!